# How to change Rails object fields after it's been paid via Stripe Checkout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In my application, a user can create a draft of an object, and then on a "finalise" view they can check if they only want the standard price or one of the two extra features as well (e.g. their entry being featured on the platform) - these are stored as three separate products each with their own price because I want to be able to track them separately in the future.

I am using Checkout for payments and my backend is Rails.

I am listening to webhooks, but I don't know how I could actually modify the object in question, since I can't see any webhook request body that contains the information I need.

What I imagine I'd need is something like this: "there has been a successful charge of `$x` related to your object with id `123`, and the charge included product `prod_asdf` and `prod_sdfg`", and then I could update e.g. the `paid` and `featured` boolean fields of my object.

This seems like a no-brainer, since the products and prices are actually handled by Stripe and they are passed to the checkout session, I don't see why I can't access them from the webhooks?

EDIT: I'm wondering if passing necessary metadata to the Session object and then using the same metadata listening to a `checkout.session.completed` event is a good idea.

Comment: Can you clarify - when you say "related to your object with id 123" do you mean an object in your own databases that has `paid` and `featured` boolean fields?

Comment: @karbi yes, I have a Listing model, and users can purchase a "standard" price, a "featured" and a "preselect" add-on for them. I need to modify instances of Listing based on which products have been purchased for which id.

Answer (score 1):

You can link a Checkout Session back to your Listing object by including the related object ID in the metadata (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-metadata) when you create the Checkout Session. When you listen for `checkout.session.completed` events, the event will come with a Checkout Session object. You can easily link the Checkout Session back to your Listing object by checking the metadata and it also has an `amount_total` field so that will tell you the total payment amount.

You can get the products included in a session from `line_items` (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items). Unfortunately, `line_items` is not included in the webhook event by default since it is expandable (https://stripe.com/docs/expand). After receiving the `checkout.session.completed` event you can use the ID to retrieve the Checkout Session with `line_items` expanded like this:

```
session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve(
  id: 'cs_test_xxx',
  expand: ['line_items'],
)
line_items = session.line_items
```

Alternatively, you can just retrieve the Checkout Session's line items (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items) like this:

```
line_items = Stripe::Checkout::Session.list_line_items('cs_test_D3OF4MY1VGflR8idkewd795t8MLd4PwA3wxdLCHikdRFTIkBecH6FKij', {limit: 5})
```